# Perform an INNER JOIN with more than 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I just recently learned about SQL `INNER JOIN`  and I thought of applying it on a project so basically I have three tables

- payers
- discounts
- items

Now I was just wondering if I can return the results from both of the three tables at once using an `INNER JOIN` with both of the 3 tables or is it only possible with 2 tables?

If it is possible to use an `INNER JOIN` with more than 2 tables then kindly please guide me on how to do it and if not then tell me how to do it in any other ways possible.

Now this is the query that I currently have which doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM payers
INNER JOIN discounts AND items
ON payers.id = discounts.id AND ON payers.id = items.id;
```

Comment: It is, of course, possible. Please show us sample data from the three tables, along with the desired results, and you current attempt.

Comment: A join links two tables, but you can have as many joins as you like

Comment: @GMB For Sure I'll include them here

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sorry I don't get what you mean by that can you please explain in a specific answer for that?

Comment: @GMB I added the query that I currently have to do this no need for sample data since I use SELECT * which automatically SELECTS all the tables I know that spelling them out is a better practice but still it's just a small project with less amount of tables so I use * to save the time.

Comment: It seems fantastically unlikely that payers and items would share a column called 'id'

Comment: @Strawberry yes that is true GMB did mention the column name overlapping in his side note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two joins. The syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM payers p
INNER JOIN discounts d ON d.id = p.id
INNER JOIN items     i ON i.id = p.id
```

Side notes:

- you did not show your actual schema, so this uses the join conditions described in your attempt; you might need to review that
- table aliases make the query shorter to write and easier to read
- `SELECT *` is generally not good practice; instead, I would recommend enumerating the columns you want in the `SELECT` clause, and properly aliasing conflicting columns names, if any (here, all three tables have a column called `id`, which would cause ambiguity in the resultset)